# WordPress - Contact Form7 - Custom Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create my own tag. (code in image)

My tag looks like this

**[Custom_views_post_title]**

At this point, the tag shows post number 1.

I would like to display any post using my tag.
For example

**[custom_views_post_title id = "2"]**

**[custom_views_post_title id = "20"]**

I am asking for help or advice

[enter my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTysW.png)

Comment: How should that tag be rendered?

Comment: @Alice, For that you have to create your own short-code by defining your own logic to render it.